# Пустыннейший/пустынейший

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: *пустыннейший* или *пустынейший*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***пустыннейший***.

Прилагательное состоит из корня -ПУСТЫН- и суффикса -Н-, поэтому, т. к. одна Н в корне, а другая в суффиксе, нужно писать **с двумя Н**.

Comment: Т. е. надо писать *травянейший*?

Comment: Такого слова нет, это относительное. Но если вы прям хотите, то с одной Н.

Comment: Хочу и буду! И точка!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Почему восклицательные знаки? Злость чувствуется. Я же не запещал использовать и не предъявлял вам за такие слова. Используйте, если хотите, что злиться-то? Или это не злость?

Comment: Это шутка конечно же-с! Я наоборот вам за столько ответов благодарен. Я — мирный Леопольд, а не тот, что озверина нажрался до полусмерти.